# jQuery Boilerplate Ability to add $.myplugin to Return Value or Object

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-boilerplate

I am creating a jQuery plugin from the [jQuery boilerplate](http://jqueryboilerplate.com). I've been successful in my implementation so far.

However, I would like my plugging to to be called like this

```
$('selector').myplugin({data}) -- and have it return a chainable object
```

or

```
$.myplugin({data}) --and have it return something (string, object, array).
```

I read around about moving the `this.each() ... return this` to each method, but I am getting

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$.myplugin()')
```

### Example:

Here's an example of what I would like to do.

```
<input class="textIn" type="text" />
<input class="textOut" type="text" />

<script>
  var input = $('.textIn').val();

  //CASE #1
  // will perform method named someMethod with an arg and return a value
  var output = $.myPlugin(someMethod, input);

  //CASE #2
  // will go through each node with class 'textOut' and perform someMethod with an arg
  $('.textOut').myPlugin(someMethod, input);

  //CASE #3
  // will go through each node with class 'textOut' and perform someOtherMethod
  $('.textOut').myPlugin(someOtherMethod);
</script>
```

Maybe case #1 and #2 cannot be combined and I will have to rename the method, but I'm not sure. Any help would be great!

Comment: what is that you want to do in the plugin?

Comment: I'll update the question with this info.